# xcode c file inside folder not executing

Tags: c, xcode, git

I imported a c project from git into Xcode, without xcodeproj.file. To do this I downloaded the repository, created a new Xcode-Project with source control enabled and then overwrote all data in that project with the data I got from my git repository, which worked fine, but now I'm unable to execute the main.c file inside Xcode, when it is in a folder:
like that: [main.c inside the Blackjack folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0loiR.png)
Xcode says error: executable doesn't exist:....
However, when I move the main.c file outside the folder, or add it as a compile source it works, but the latter moves it outside the folder [too.][2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLunM.png
Is there a way to add it as a compile target, without moving it outside the folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the disclosure triangle next to the Compile Sources build phase in your screenshot. Click the Add (+) button to add a new file to compile. A sheet opens. Select the main.c file and click the Add button to add main.c to the list of source files to compile.

Comment: In the end it wasn't exactly the fault I did. But it pointed me to another mistake I did, by adding the folder with the option "add folder references" enabled, while it should have been "Create Groups", which prevented me from being able to select the main.c file in the mentioned sheet. So thanks for your answer.